# Proof of Stein's Lemma. Why is this last term zero?

Tags: integration, statistics, expected-value, variance

I must be overlooking something simple. I found [these notes online Lemma 3.6.5](http://www.math.ntu.edu.tw/%7Ehchen/teaching/StatInference/notes/lecture21.pdf) and I cannot understand why the last term in Here is 0...

I will restate the Lemma from the paper below with slight alterations in the derivation because I was working through it in my own way...

**Lemma 3.6.5 (Stein's Lemma)**

Let $X \sim N(\theta, \sigma^2)$, and let $g$ be a differentiable function satisfying $\mathbb{E}[|g'(X)|] \lt \infty$. Then

$$
\mathbb{E}[g(X)(X - \theta)] = \sigma^2\mathbb{E}[g'(X)]
$$

**Proof**

We can evaluate the left hand side using integration by parts $u = g(x)$ and $dv = (x - \theta)e^{-\frac{(x - \theta)^2}{2\sigma^2}}$ which means that $v = -\sigma^2e^{-\frac{(x - \theta)^2}{2\sigma^2}}$

$$
\begin{aligned}
\mathbb{E}[g(x)(X - \theta)] &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma} \int g(x)(x - \theta)e^{-\frac{(x - \theta)^2}{2\sigma^2}}dx \\
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma} 
\Bigg(
\Big[
-\sigma^2g(x)e^{-\frac{(x - \theta)^2}{2\sigma^2}}
\Big]_{-\infty}^{\infty}
- \int -\sigma^2g'(x)e^{-\frac{(x - \theta)^2}{2\sigma^2}}dx
\Bigg) \\
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma} 
\Bigg(
\int \sigma^2g'(x)e^{-\frac{(x - \theta)^2}{2\sigma^2}}dx
- \Big[
\sigma^2g(x)e^{-\frac{(x - \theta)^2}{2\sigma^2}}
\Big]_{-\infty}^{\infty}
\Bigg) \\
&= \sigma^2 \mathbb{E}[g'(x)]
- \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}\Big[
\sigma^2g(x)e^{-\frac{(x - \theta)^2}{2\sigma^2}}
\Big]_{-\infty}^{\infty} \\
\end{aligned}
$$

The notes then say that

> The condition on $g'$ is enough to ensure that the last term is 0 and what remains on the RHS is $\sigma^2 \mathbb{E}[g'(x)]$

I must be missing something simple, but I cannot see why the last term there should be zero. Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any $t\in \mathbb{R}$, we have $$|g'(t)| e^{-(x-\theta)^2/(2\sigma^2)}\cdot 1_{[\theta,x]}(t) \leq |g'(t)|e^{-(t-\theta)^2/(2\sigma^2)},$$
where we recognize the dominating function as integrable by assumption and independent of $x$.  Additionally, as $x\to\infty$, the smaller function goes to $0$ pointwise for every $t$.  Therefore, by the Dominated Convergence Theorem,
$$\begin{align*}\lim_{x\to\infty} g(x)e^{-(x-\theta)^2/(2\sigma^2)} &= \lim_{x\to\infty} (g(x)-g(\theta))e^{-(x-\theta)^2/(2\sigma^2)} \\ &= \lim_{x\to\infty} \int_\theta^x g'(t)e^{-(x-\theta)^2/(2\sigma^2)}\,dt \\ &= 0\end{align*}$$

This gives half of the result.  Showing the other half is similar.

---

On notation:

- I use the notation $1_A(t)$ is $1$ if $t\in A$ and $0$ otherwise.

Comment: It took me a while to intuitively understand this, but I think I got it. Can it be summed up as "the existence of an expectation less than infinity implies that $g(\infty) = 0$" (and likewise for $-\infty$)

Comment: @Joff The limit of $g$ at $\pm \infty$ need not be $0$, so if that's what you mean by $g(\infty)=0$, then that's incorrect.  However, the assumption that $g$ is differentiable with $g'(X)$ integrable implies that $g(x)\phi(x) \to 0$ as $x\to \pm \infty$ when $\phi$ is the normal pdf.  This definitely implies that the difference of the two limits is zero (which is precisely what you need to show)

Comment: If I'm correct, the result on the limit can be generalized further.  We need only assume $g$ is absolutely continuous (as opposed to differentiable), $X$ is a random variable with pdf $\phi$, and there is some $N$ such that $\phi$ is monotone increasing on $(-\infty, -N]$ and monotone decreasing on $[N, \infty)$ (as opposed to being a normal pdf in particular).  --- Stein's lemma actually holds in the absolutely continuous case of $g$, but since Stein's lemma characterizes normal distributions, we of course cannot get Stein's lemma itself for the case of more general $\phi$.

Comment: My first comment was sloppy. I might be confused, or I might need to take some more time to study the dominated convergence theorem...But now that I look at it again, couldn't be as simple as saying the exponential term is zero at both $\pm \infty$?

Comment: @Joff There's no reason that $g$ is bounded, so no, it's not sufficient to just recognize $\lim_{x\to\pm\infty} e^{-(x-\theta)^2/(2\sigma^2)} = 0$.  [this is assuming you're talking about $\lim_{x\to\pm\infty} g(x)e^{-(x-\theta)^2/(2\sigma^2)}$... if you are talking about the dominated convergence theorem, then the pointwise convergence to zero in fact is given by the limit of the exponential factor as $x\to\pm\infty$]